# Postgresql abnormal database system shutdown

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am very new to both aws ec2 instances and postgresql. I was able to get a database up and working for a web application mainly using the phppgadmin interface. Today I was working on my web app and was abruptly disconnected from the database. In my web app I got the error " pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused\n Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" I now can't log in to phppg admin or connect to postgres from my ec2 instance command line. After inspecting the log file at /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log I am seeing the error  "FATAL:  could not open file "global/pg_filenode.map": Permission denied" followed by "LOG: abnormal database system shutdown" I have my pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files are configured correctly as I have been doing work on this database for a few days now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You or something else wrecked your PostgreSQL installation by changing permissions on or ownership of PostgreSQL files. On Windows and its interesting concepts of file locking, I'd suspect an anti-virus program, but you seem to be running some kind of Unix. Little more can be said with the little information in the question.